# Trouble splitting data in Java program

Tags: java

I'm trying to split my variables and enter my student data in so I can move on with my grade calculation program, but my second time splitting the entered string, there is a problem and I cannot figure out what is the cause of it.

Users will enter information in that looks like this
John Denver: e100 q70 q50 h100 e100 e90 h80 q60 h100

The program needs to split apart all of this data and get the name entered into an array, and then the exam scores, quiz scores and homework scores represented by the "e", "q" or "h" in the entered data.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeCalcWithArrays { /*
                                 * Daniel The purpose is to calculate
                                 * entered grades
                                 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean done = false;
    boolean quit = false;
    int choice = 0;
    int maxstudents = 200;

    int[] examstats = new int[3]; /*
                                 * Array created to store the information
                                 * entered for exams
                                 */
    int[] quizstats = new int[3]; /*
                                 * Array created to store the information
                                 * entered for quizzes
                                 */
    int[] homeworkstats = new int[3]; /*
                                     * Array created to store the
                                     * information entered for homework
                                     */

    String[] studentnames = new String[maxstudents]; /*
                                                     * Array created to
                                                     * store the student
                                                     * name information
                                                     * entered
                                                     */

    System.out.println("Welcome to GradeBook!");
    System.out.println("Please provide grade item details");

    System.out.print("Exams    (number, points, weight):");

    examstats[0] = s.nextInt(); // inputs exam number
    examstats[1] = s.nextInt(); // inputs exam points
    examstats[2] = s.nextInt(); // inputs exam weight

    System.out.print("Quizzes     (number, points, weight):");

    quizstats[0] = s.nextInt(); // inputs quiz number
    quizstats[1] = s.nextInt(); // inputs quiz points
    quizstats[2] = s.nextInt(); // inputs quiz weight

    System.out.print("Homework    (number, points, weight):");

    homeworkstats[0] = s.nextInt(); // inputs homework number
    homeworkstats[1] = s.nextInt(); // inputs homework points
    homeworkstats[2] = s.nextInt(); // inputs homework weight

    double[] examscores = new double[examstats[0]];
    double[] quizscores = new double[quizstats[0]];
    double[] hwscores = new double[homeworkstats[0]];

    System.out.println("--------------------");

    do {
        System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("    1 Add student data");
        System.out.println("    2 Display student grades & statistics");
        System.out.println("    3 Plot grade distribution");
        System.out.println("    4 Quit");
        System.out.print("Your choice:");
        choice = s.nextInt(); /*
                             * Choice will determine what the next course of
                             * action will be with the program
                             */

        if (choice == 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter student data:");

            for (int i = 0; i <= maxstudents; i++) {
                System.out.print("Data>");
                String dataentry = s.nextLine();

                String[] firstsplit = dataentry.split(":");
                studentnames[i] = firstsplit[0];
                String[] secondsplit = firstsplit[1].split(" ");

                for (int j = 0; j <= maxstudents; j++) {

                    String c;

                    c = secondsplit[j].substring(0, 1);

                    if (c == "e") {
                        secondsplit = secondsplit[j].split("e");
                        examscores[i] = Double.parseDouble(secondsplit[j]);

                    }
                    if (c == "q") {
                        secondsplit = secondsplit[j].split("q");
                        quizscores[i] = Double.parseDouble(secondsplit[j]);

                    }
                    if (c == "h") {
                        secondsplit = secondsplit[j].split("h");
                        hwscores[i] = Double.parseDouble(secondsplit[j]);

                    }

                    if (dataentry.equals("done")) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (choice == 2) {

        }

        if (choice == 3) {

        }

        if (choice == 4) {
            quit = true;
            System.out.println("Good bye!");
        }

    } while (quit == false);

}

}
```

I get an error that says: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at GradeCalcWithArrays.main(GradeCalcWithArrays.java:83)

Can someone help me fix this and tell me if my program is going to work?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is wrong is that you have maxstudents set to 200, you allocate the studentnames array with size 200, but that means that the valid subscripts are 0 through 199, but your for loop uses a less than *or equal* test against 200:

```
        `for (int i = 0; i <= maxstudents; i++)`
```

That means that `i` is 200 on the last iteration, so in that iteration your code will effectively execute `studentnames[200] = firstsplit[0];` and that will cause an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

The above, however, will be a problem if you reach the 200th iteration without breaking out of the for loop. Looking at the code, I do see that you are attempting to break if the input is "done", however that break statement is actually inside the nested for loop, so it does not break out of the outer loop. That test really should happen before you do the first split. There's no reason to even try to split if the input was "done", so also no reason to go into the nested for loop.

There are additional problems as well: The nested for loop should not be testing against maxstudents because it's the number of grades that you care about. I'll leave the rest of them for you to figure out - with a hint about one of them: you should be checking your input for errors.